# Why it's not showing render html in zap attack proxy (zap)?

Tags: security, zap, penetration-tools

I am using zed attack proxy tool. It's not showing rendered html in response tab in new version. What's the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem

- Rendered HTML is less interesting for analyzing what the result and effect is of an attack. The source gives more information, it shows what the attack did with your page.
- If you right click in the response screen and click Open URL in Browser, you probably get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Have you got the latest version of the 'Browser View' add-on?
If you've updated to the latest version of ZAP then you'll probably need to download the most recent version.